# jQuery Phone Validation dosen't work after refresh page

Tags: jquery

I have script

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
var phoneInput = $('.custom-options').val(372);
var inputCart = $('.wc-variation-selection-needed');
inputCart.attr('disabled','disabled');

  phoneInput.keyup(function() {
   if (!phoneInput.val().match(/^372\d{8}$/)) {
    inputCart.attr('disabled','disabled');
   } else {
    inputCart.removeAttr('disabled');
   }
  });
});
```

this work, but only once, if i click the button and send form, inputCart will be still enable.

Comment: How do you "send form" and subsequently regenerate the form?  Add the keyup code there as well or use dynamic binding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a good practice to use `prop("disabled", true)` and `prop("disabled", false)` to enable/disable the element